# OpenLayers 3 supported formats

Tags: openlayers

What are the formats supported by OpenLayers 3?

I need open in OpenLayers a map with different colors, like the image below. So, which format should I export? I'm using QGIS and ArcMap to create the maps.

[image: map inage]

This map represents the Brazil population by regions (the darker the color, the greater the population). The data is coming from a shapefile where each row represents one different region (5570 regions in total).

Shapefile attribute table (example):

[image]

Comment: I have a solution at this **[Stackoverflow quesion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452408/openlayers-3-supported-formats/40139813#40139813)**. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

For small data sets you can use KML or GML formats. For larger data sets you had better to use WMTS/WMS/WFS server.

Comment: I've tried to export to GeoJSON, GML and KML formats and the result was the same: only the borders (contour of the regions) appeared, but I need the color appears too. What do I suppose to do?

Comment: If you would like to use multiple styles on your layer you should use styles in openlayers (http://openlayersbook.github.io/ch06-styling-vector-layers/example-07.html) or set up styles for example in your KML file.